# How to convert a string to UTF-16?

Tags: java, utf-16

I am converting the below object code to java, but the java code does not  give me the same result as this code

```
NSData *inputData = [pm dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF16LittleEndianStringEncoding];
NSString *encodedString = [inputData base64EncodedString];
pm = [IFunctions replaceString:encodedString replaceChar:@"=" replaceWithChar:@"-"];
```

Java code:

```
String s_decoded = new String(pm.getBytes(), "UTF-16LE");
pm = Base64.encode(s_decoded.getBytes()).toString().replace("=", "-");
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The no-arg getBytes() method uses the platform default encoding, which is probably not UTF-16LE.  Try `getBytes("UTF-16LE")`.

Answer (score 1):

```
byte[]   bytesEncoded = Base64.encodeBase64(str.getBytes("UTF-16LE"));
String stringEncoded = new String(bytesEncoded);
```

Answer (score 0):

Refer to this code and modify yours.

```
public class UseTheForce {
        public static void main(final String[] args)
            throws java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException {
            for (final byte b : args[0].getBytes(args[1])) {
                System.out.printf("%1$02X ", (b & 0xFF));
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
    Test

    $ java UseTheForce luke US-ASCII
    6C 75 6B 65

    $ java UseTheForce luke UTF-8
    6C 75 6B 65

    $ java UseTheForce luke UTF-16
    FE FF 00 6C 00 75 00 6B 00 65

    $ java UseTheForce luke UTF-16BE
    00 6C 00 75 00 6B 00 65

    $ java UseTheForce luke UTF-16LE
    6C 00 75 00 6B 00 65 00

    $ java UseTheForce luke UTF-32
    00 00 00 6C 00 00 00 75 00 00 00 6B 00 00 00 65
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `getBytes()` method and specify desired charset:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
    char ch;
    ch = 0x0001;
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString((String.valueOf(ch)).getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_16LE)));
    ch = 0x0111;
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString((String.valueOf(ch)).getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_16LE)));
    ch = 0x1111;
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString((String.valueOf(ch)).getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_16LE)));
}
```

***Output:***

```
[1, 0]
[17, 1]
[17, 17]
```

I used `getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_16LE)`